# fscanf inside a loop

Tags: c, scanf

Ah, thanks!  Makes sense. Just made command of size MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH + 1.

I am trying to to use fscanf to read the same file 2 different times in a loop but I am getting a seg fault.  The idea is that the file will be formatted so that it has a command at the beginning of each line, followed by arguments for the command.

```
  char* command;  //Changed to char command[MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH + 1]

  while(fscanf(file, "%s", command) == 1)
  {
    if (strcmp("CMD1", command) == 0)
    {    
      int index, exp, coeff;
      fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &index, &exp, &coeff);
    }
    else if (strcmp("CMD2", command) == 0)
    {
      int num;
      fscanf(file, "%d", &num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading through a file twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `command`. For example:

```
command = (char *)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
```

will allocate enough memory for 1024 characters.

Remember to `free(command)` when you're finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate some storage and store it in 'command'. You are asking fscanf to write through an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you just have a pointer. You need to allocate some space to hold the string you read:

```
char command[256];

if (fscanf(file "%256s", command)==1)
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate a buffer to read the command. Currently `command` is not initialized and it points to sum invalid address. So either you "malloc()" memory for command or declare command as an array (`char command[whateversizeyouneed]`)